# How to get the data from API and put into tha table (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Trying to store all the information that getting from JSONP in the table.
Have done the test with 'alert' to make sure that there are more info that only one line and can see that there are more info that one.
But when run it, in the table I can see title row and first row.
Can somebody correct my error?

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script> 

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
            $.ajax({ 
                url : "http://api.example.com/v1/deal/hotel?apikey=xxx&format=JSONP", 
                dataType : "jsonp",
                success : function(parsed_json) { 

                    $.each(parsed_json.Result, function( index, value ) {
                    alert( index + ": " + value.StarRating + " , "+ value.Url);

                });

                var from = parsed_json['Result'][0]['StartDate']; 
                document.getElementById("from").innerHTML = from;

                var from = parsed_json['Result'][0]['StartDate']; 
                document.getElementById("from").innerHTML = from;

                var to = parsed_json['Result'][0]['EndDate']; 
                document.getElementById("to").innerHTML = to;

                var nights = parsed_json['Result'][0]['NightDuration']; 
                document.getElementById("nights").innerHTML = nights;

                var currency = parsed_json['Result'][0]['CurrencyCode']; 
                document.getElementById("currency").innerHTML = currency;           

                var price = parsed_json['Result'][0]['Price']; 
                document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = price;

                var link = parsed_json['Result'][0]['Url']; 
                document.getElementById("link").innerHTML = link;
                //how to represent enlaces

                var city = parsed_json['Result'][0]['City']; 
                document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = city;

                var country = parsed_json['Result'][0]['CountryCode']; 
                document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = country;

                var stars = parsed_json['Result'][0]['StarRating']; 
                document.getElementById("stars").innerHTML = stars; 

                }
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <table id="t">
        <tr>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>End date</th>
            <th>Nights</th>
            <th>Currency</th>
            <th>Price</th> 
            <th>Link</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Country Code</th>
            <th>Star Rating</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="from"></td> 
            <td id="to"></td>
            <td id="nights"></td>
            <td id="currency"></td>
            <td id="price"></td> 
            <td id="link"></td>
            <td id="city"></td>
            <td id="country"></td>
            <td id="stars"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The result of the Ajax callback is:

> callback({"Errors":[],"Result":[{"FoundDate":"2013-12-04T16:11:36-08:00","CurrencyCode":"USD","NightDuration":"2.0","EndDate":"12/08/2013","Headline":"Cairo 5 Star Hotel, $36/night","IsWeekendStay":"true","Price":"36.0","StartDate":"12/06/2013","Url":"http‍://www.example.com/hotel/...&startDate=12/06/2013&endDate=12/08/2013&bid=0&sid=0","City":"Cairo","CountryCode":"EG","NeighborhoodLatitude":"30.0152","NeighborhoodLongitude":"31.1756","Neighborhood":"Cairo West - Giza","StarRating":"5.0","StateCode":"EG"},{"FoundDate":"2013-12-04T14:51:44-08:00",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have more than one line in result, then you have to -

1. Loop through it in the callback. You are not looping through it now. You are looping only for alert.
2. Dynamically create a new row in table for each line. You can clone the exiting `tr` for this using `jquery clone` method. But replace the `id` with 'class`.
3. Add data to that row pertaining to the line by modifying innerHtml of each td in the newly created row.
4. Finally, Append the row to the table

HTML -

```
<table id="t">
    <tr>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>End date</th>
        <th>Nights</th>
        <th>Currency</th>
        <th>Price</th> 
        <th>Link</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Country Code</th>
        <th>Star Rating</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="first">
        <td class="from"></td> 
        <td class="to"></td>
        <td class="nights"></td>
        <td class="currency"></td>
        <td class="price"></td> 
        <td class="link"></td>
        <td class="city"></td>
        <td class="country"></td>
        <td class="stars"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript -

```
success : function(parsed_json) { 
              $.each(parsed_json.Result, function( index, record ) {  
                 $row = $('.first').clone();          
                 var from = record['StartDate']; 
                 $row.find('.from').html(from);
                 //Similarly repeat the above two lines for other columns
                 //...
                 $('#t').append($row);
              });
          }
```

Comment: is there any way to do it using appendTo ?